# How to validate an element in xml using regular expression

Tags: xml

Here i am trying to validate the reference number field which should allow only specific characters like  'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9', '-' and '_'.How can i do it?

```
<field name="txtNumeroDossier" type="texte" maxlength="15" focus="true">
    <description_f>Votre numéro de référence</description_f>
    <description_a>Your reference number</description_a>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [XSD schema](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) for validation, create new `.xsd` file:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="SNAPSHOT" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <!-- create new simple type for description fields,
       restriction by pattern will validate by regexp -->
  <xs:simpleType name="description">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-z0-9\-_]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <!-- field root element type declaration -->
  <xs:complexType name="field">
    <xs:all>
      <!-- description elements of type description with validation -->
      <xs:element name="description_f" type="description"/>
      <xs:element name="description_a" type="description"/>
    </xs:all>
    <!-- attributes -->
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="maxlength" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="focus" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!-- root element declaration of type field -->
  <xs:element name="field" type="field"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: i cant use this format.is there any way to use "regex" validator or "pattern" attribute

Comment: @raj xml can't perform validation itself, you have to use xsd schema or write validation code on application side.